# Getting stackoverflow error writing to realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to upload an object to Firebase database, but when I do so I get a stackoverflowerror. I saw a lot a people getting this error but their solutions didn't work in my case. The only thing I could achieve was to write a single String variable.

I tried to: Check all my Object variables are the permitted by Firebase serialization

This is the code:

**The object**

```
package chtecnologies.lola.entities;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Pet {

private String id;
private String name;
private String breed;
private String type;
private String pictures;
private String description;
private String location;
private String locality;
private String gender;
private String age;
private String userid;

public Pet(String id, String name, String breed, String type, String description,
           String pictures, String location, String locality, String gender,
           String age, String userid) {

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.type = type;
    this.description = description;
    this.pictures = pictures;
    this.location = location;
    this.locality = locality;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.userid = userid;
}

public Pet(String breed, String type, String pictures, String description, String location, String locality, String gender, String age, String userid) {
    /** CONSTRUCTOR FOR ADOPTABLE PET**/
    this.breed = breed;
    this.type = type;
    this.pictures = pictures;
    this.description = description;
    this.location = location;
    this.locality = locality;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.age = age;
    this.userid = userid;
}

public Pet(String name, String breed, String type, String pictures, String description, String location, String locality, String userid) {
/** CONSTRUCTOR FOR LOST PET**/

    this.name = name;
    this.breed = breed;
    this.type = type;
    this.pictures = pictures;
    this.description = description;
    this.location = location;
    this.locality = locality;
    this.userid = userid;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getBreed() {
    return breed;
}

public void setBreed(String breed) {
    this.breed = breed;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getPictures() {
    return pictures;
}

public void setPictures(String pictures) {
    this.pictures = pictures;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

public String getLocality(){ return locality; }

public void setLocality(String locality){
    this.locality = locality;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getGender() {
    return gender;
}

public void setGender(String gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public Pet getPet(){
    return this;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Pet{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", breed='" + breed + '\'' +
            ", type='" + type + '\'' +
            ", pictures=" + pictures +
            ", description='" + description + '\'' +
            ", location='" + location + '\'' +
            ", locality='" + locality + '\'' +
            ", gender='" + gender + '\'' +
            ", age='" + age + '\'' +
            ", userid='" + userid + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

**The method that writes to the database:**

```
@Override
public void postPet(Pet pet) {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference();

 //        TODO: Next line throwing stackoverflow error
    ref.push().setValue(pet);

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
 }
```

**The Logcat**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: chtecnologies.lola, PID: 11761
                                                                java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:58)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at 
                                                                       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at    com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
03-20 12:28:55.008 11761-11761/chtecnologies.lola E/AndroidRuntime:        at       com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzca(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelx.zzcb(Unknown Source:120)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbx(Unknown Source:237)
                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelw.zzbw(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.zza(Unknown Source:10)
                                                                    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(Unknown Source:7)
                                                                    at chtecnologies.lola.ui.activities.LoadPresenter.postPet(LoadPresenter.java:144)
                                                                    at chtecnologies.lola.ui.activities.LoadPresenter.checkFieldsLost(LoadPresenter.java:132)
                                                                    at chtecnologies.lola.ui.activities.PostLostActivity$3.onClick(PostLostActivity.java:101)
                                                                    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I deleted some identical lines because I was exceeding the characters

I'm new to Firebase and I was trying to change my actual storage database to Firebase, but I can't make it work. I read the the documentation, and I can't see I'm doing anything not permited. I hope you can help me to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: If you're seeing a crash, copy the entire stack trace into your question.

Comment: I updated the post

Comment: Your 'getPet' is causing a recursive firebase push.  Firebase uses reflection to find all the 'getters' which in this case is finding 'getPet' which evidently is a reference to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the no-argument constructor in your `Pet` class because is needed for Firebase.

```
public Pet() {}
```

and remove these lines:

```
public Pet getPet(){
    return this;
}
```

When the Firebase Realtime database SDK deserializes objects that are coming from the database, it requires that any objects in use, to have a `public no-argument constructor`, so it can use it to instantiate the object. Fields in the objects are set by using public setter methods or direct access to public members.

If your pet object dosen't have a `public no-arg constructor`, the SDK doesn't really know how to create an instance of it. So it is mandatory to have it.

Comment: I tried implementing Serializable class and it didn’t work. But i had not the empty constructor. I’ll fix it and I’ll get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Ok, keep me posted. Don't also forget to remove `getPet()` method. It must be a consctructor and not a method.

Comment: It worked! The method causing the error was getPet(), and I also added the empty constructor. However I didn't implement the Serializable class and it is working, do you suggest to implement it anyway?

Comment: Glad to head that it worked. No, all your fields in this moment are serializable, because are strings. Updated my answer.